# PHP - Variável de sessão não apresenta novo conteúdo

Tags: php

Desenvolvi um sistema com PHP e estou tendo problemas com variáveis de sessão ($_SESSION). Uma página atribui um valor a uma variável de sessão e chama uma outra página. Esta outra página recebe o valor corretamente somente na primeira chamada. A partir da segunda chamada, o valor da variável de sessão permanece o anterior, mesmo tendo sido atualizada com valor diferente. Se executo um refresh da página no browser, o valor da variável apresenta o valor correto. Porém esse valor é o que vai permanecer até que um novo refresh seja executado no browser. Isto ocorre tanto no Google Chrome quanto no Internet Explorer.
Não tenho idéia do porque isso está ocorrendo e nem como resolver ou contornar a situação.

Criei duas páginas que reproduzem fielmente o problema:

```
//PAGINA 1:

header('Cache-Control: no cache');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');

session_start();

echo '<br>ANTES';
if (isset($_SESSION['var1']))
    echo '<br>var1=' . $_SESSION['var1'];
else
    echo '<br>var1 não existe';
echo '<br>';

$_SESSION['var1'] = 'T';
echo '<br>conteudo var1 alterado para T<br>';

echo '<br>DEPOIS';
if (isset($_SESSION['var1']))
    echo '<br>var1=' . $_SESSION['var1'];
else
    echo '<br>var1 não existe';
echo '<br>';

echo '<br><a href="pagina2.php"><input type="button" value="Vai p/ pagina 2"></a>';


//PAGINA 2:

header('Cache-Control: no cache');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');

session_start();

echo '<br>ANTES';
if (isset($_SESSION['var1']))
    echo '<br>var1=' . $_SESSION['var1'];
else
    echo '<br>var1 não existe';
echo '<br>';

$_SESSION['var1'] = '';
echo '<br>conteudo var1 alterado para NULL<br>';

echo '<br>DEPOIS';
if (isset($_SESSION['var1']))
    echo '<br>var1=' . $_SESSION['var1'];
else
    echo '<br>var1 não existe';
echo '<br>';

echo '<br><a href="pagina1.php"><input type="button" value="Vai p/ pagina 1"></a>';
```

Comment: Na sua pergunta, coloque o resultado que está aparecendo no exemplo para que entendamos o que você espera que saia e o que está sendo exibido.

Comment: Na primeira chamada da pagina 1, a variável var1 apresenta:
ANTES: "var1 não existe"
DEPOIS: "var1=T"

Após clicar o botão "Vai p/pagina2" a página 2 apresenta:
ANTES: "var1=NULL" <-- deveria apresentar o valor "T" atribuido pela pagina 1 (este é o problema)
DEPOIS: "var1=NULL"

Comment: Acabo de reproduzir os passos descritos e a página 2 apresentou: `ANTES var1=T`.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo que citou aqui está aparecendo.

Caso esteja ocorrendo este problema em seu sistema verifique se é alguma parte do código está atribuindo o valor NULL ou "" vazio para a sessão.

E verifique se está fazendo a chamada do session_start() no início do código.

Comigo já ocorreu erro de por exemplo eu atribuir o valor da sessão em uma variável, após modificar a variável alterou o valor da sessão também. Verifique se não fez isso também.

```
//Exemplo do que citei acima
$login = $_SESSION['login'];

$login = false; 
//No sistema o valor da sessão também foi alterado
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo, obrigado a todos que responderam à minha questão.
Reeditei os códigos publicados nessa questão, colocando as duas linhas abaixo:

header('Cache-Control: no cache');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');

E foram essas duas declarações que omití na questão original e que causaram o problema no comportamento das variáveis de sessão. Após terem sido removidas no meu código, as variáveis de sessão passaram a ter o comportamento esperado.